# Cron job using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Need a line of code using Laravel framework that will:

- Add a cron job
- List the current cron jobs
- Modify a cron job

The business scenario I got is making recurring payments for customers using my charge.php file, but I wanna manage/delete/add subscriptions.

Straight-forward codes are welcomed.

Comment: This is too broad. What's your actual question?

Comment: I'm asking specifically how can you manage cron jobs using php code solely and not using shell crontab -e command. in a Laravel controller for instance?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at all? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Answer (score 1):

cron jobs in laravel known by commands name,

creating cron job :
    **php artisan make:console HappyBirthday --command=sms:birthday**
this will create a php file under **app/Commands/** directory

for see the list : **php artisan list**

for more information check the link : https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/

Comment: Cool, but I'm asking specifically how can you do that using php code solely. in a Laravel controller for instance?

Comment: if you want to run the command through your php code take a look at this code : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code